# Send connections from minecraft port 25565 to another server

Tags: tcp, port-forwarding, minecraft

I have a domain name *domain1.com* and I want if someone want to connect (via minecraft) on port 25565 that the connection is transfered to another server.

So: connect to *domain1.com*:25565 ==> something listens on 25565 ==> transferes the Connection to *gameserver.com:25565*

I did looked into nginx but I saw that it doesnt work for the "minecraft" protocol.

What other Option do I have?

Comment: Read up on [tag:ssh], and using it for port forwards. maybe checkout `autossh` too. Oh, and your problem is not specific to minecraft. Execute on gamserver something like `ssh -R 25565:localhost:25565 domain1.com`

Comment: I think what you want is to have an srv record on your domain for minecraft. You would need to set that on your Name servers control panel. Usually where you got your domain from or use another Name server.